# Foreign keys and uploading a photo in yii 1.1

Tags: mysql, yii, upload, foreign-keys, photo

i did these two tasks separately but now i am not being able to use both of these tasks at a single place.

Problem statement:

I have a table name `Business_items` having foreign keys of table `business` and `items`. In model class here is the relation function.

```
 public function relations()
        {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                'business' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Business', 'business_id'),
                'items' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Items', 'items_id'),
                'itemReviews' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ItemReview', 'business_items_id'),
            );
        }
```

ok, in create business page, i have two fields, `business name, items name` and a third thing which is `upload image`. Both of the fields are searchable drop downs. I am taking business name and items name with the help of foreign keys. so i can see the values inside my `business_items` which were used to be keys. i did this by changing this code.

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model=new PackageItems;

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if(isset($_POST['PackageItems']))
            {
   $temp=$model->items_id=$_POST['PackageItems']['items_id']; //items_id is a multiple list field

                         foreach($temp as $t)
                          {
                             $model->unsetAttributes();
                             $model->setIsNewRecord(true);
                               $model->package_id=$_POST['PackageItems']['package_id']; //package_id is a repeated field

                             $model->items_id=$t;

                         $model->insert();

                        }
                if($model->save())
                    $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$model->id));
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            ));
        }
```

so what i wanted i actually accomplished which was 
    id----items----package
    1------cake-----buy one get one free
    2----- pastry-----buy one get one free

second part:
I know how to upload image in yii, i followed this link and it worked `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/349/how-to-upload-image-photo-and-path-entry-in-database-with-update-functionality/`
separately now the problem is i want something like that

```
 id----items----package-----------------------image
    1------cake-----buy one get one free------1.jpg
    2----- pastry-----buy one get one free------1.jpg
```

but the problem is

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Banner;  // this is my model related to table
        if(isset($_POST['Banner']))
        {
            $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Banner'];

            $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
            $model->image = $fileName;

            if($model->save())
            {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../banner/'.$fileName);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/banner/
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
        }
        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

how can i use both of these codes (getting value using foreign key code and picture uploading code) i want to upload pictures as well as get the value from some other table using foreign key with my code.
I know its complicated but i need help.
Thanks and sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your problem right, but as far as I understood, you want to upload a file and insert the name of this file in one of your database tables. If that's the case, a solution could be as follows:
First, add a new field to your database table in which you will store the file name, also add it to your ActiveRecord class and to your view.
Then add your code to save your related records (I think your foreach loop is for that).
Next add a the necessary code to upload the image. In the code to upload the image you can see that Yii will treat the file field like a normal text field, in which you will store the uploaded file name. 
Finally you should save your model and, if it succeded, then proceed to save the file in the server.
Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
I'll put some code in order to clarify my answer.

You say that the first part works for you, then I'll begin with that. 
Your model PackageItems needs a new field, let it be image.
Next, I'm assuming that the user filled the form, so I'll skip the if and the render parts

```
   $temp=$model->items_id=$_POST['PackageItems']['items_id'];
   $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');//get uploaded image info
   $rnd = rand(0,9999);
   $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
   $model->image = $fileName;//store the new file name in the model 
   foreach($temp as $t){
     $model->unsetAttributes();
     $model->setIsNewRecord(true);
     $model->package_id=$_POST['PackageItems']['package_id'];
     $model->items_id=$t;
     $model->insert();
   }
   if($model->save()){
     $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../yourPath/'.$fileName);//if the record was saved in the database, then proceed to save the image in the server 
     $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$model->id));
   }
```

If you want to upload multiple files check this link [Yii 1.1: Uploading multiple images with CMultiFileUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/176/uploading-multiple-images-with-cmultifileupload/)

Comment: oh let me explain, i want to upload a picture, as well as using foreign key, i want to retrieve the items_name and package_name from the foreign table.